# Ошибка при вводе в input

Tags: python

Не понимаю из за чего вылетает ошибка ...

пробовала и так

```
ask = str(input("Сохранить изменения? [Y/n]"))
print(ask)
```

и так

```
 ask = input("Сохранить изменения? [Y/n]")
    print(ask)
```

*Ошибка:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 5, in <module>
    ask = input("Сохранить изменения? [Y/n]")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Comment: У вас в коде(до этого) где-то используется переменная 'test' возможно в функции или цикле, которая до этого не обозначалась. Скиньте полный код

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, нет переменная тест не используется нигде. Это тестовый файл на несколько строк кода, для того чтобы разобраться с ошибкой

Comment: а какая версия питона? Случайно не вторая?

Comment: Удалите второй питон и поставьте третий питон

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, Python 3.7.3

Comment: @Christiana в Python 3.7.3 показанный вами код отлично работает

Comment: Что находится в четырёх строках до этого?

Comment: У вас код запускается во второй версии питона, а не в третьей. Или вы ошибаетесь с тем, что у вас установлено, или вам нужно подправить переменные окружения.

Answer (score 0):

Данный код корректно работает в компиляторе 3.6.8
https://repl.it/languages/python3 .
Возможные ошибки

1. У вас установлен python2
2. Некорректная установка компилятора
3. Некорректная установка ide

Попробуйте просто вывести   print("1")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ну для начала хочу сказать что у вас вероятно установлен второй питон, а это не редко приводит к подобным ошибкам.

На третьем питоне ваш код работает без каких-либо проблем.

Во вторых у вас выводятся две ошибки.

На счёт второй точно не уверен, но предполагаю вы отправили неполный код и до этого неправильно использовалась переменная 'test' вероятно переменная использовалась в локальной области видимости (внутри функции и т.п.)

Если это так то внутри функции перед переменной test введите слово global

```
global test
```

это сделает переменную test глобальной

Но если она не в локальной области видимости, то опять же это может быть из за версии питона или неправильном присваивании значения к имени.

Comment: Выводит два сообщения, но на самом деле ошибка одна (NameError). Если во втором питоне запустить данный код, то будет именно такое сообщение. Только что проверил.